# How to show text in bash command line (like the `write` command does)?

Tags: bash

I want to write a bash script to pop text on one's terminal in a way just like one receives a message from `write` but without using `write`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
echo "hi" | write $(whoami) $(tty)
```

or without `write`

```
echo "hi" > $(tty)
```

If you want to send a message to other users, you can obtain a map of tty and logged-in users using the `who` command.

Comment: Do you know how to implement this without using `write` ?

Comment: permissions will get in the way of doing this without `write`